# How do I remove the space between two CSS floats?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a page designed for tabbed page navigation. The top tabs are `<li>`s in a `<ul>` and nested in parent divs and a topmost header div. The header div consists of 3 child divs, `logo`, `logo2`, and `menu`. The logo div is set to float left and other two to float right. But there is some unwanted space (or a fluid gap) between `logo2` div and `menu` div. I want no space (or a space of single px) between these divs. You can see a working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/wVBxy/)**. How can I solve this?

I am getting this

[image]

and I want this

[image]

Comment: What browser are you looking at this in? I'm seeing very different results in different browsers.

Comment: Your description and fiddle don't seem to clearly show the problem because I don't think I'm seeing the same as you.  I just don't see any space between `#menu` and `#logo2`.  I only see a large fluid gap between `#logo` and `#logo2` which is working exactly as programmed.  Screenshot(s) would help.

Comment: Thanks for posting the images.  In Safari, it's already working exactly as you want.

Comment: hi @Sparky672, i like safari, but do u know y its getting stuck in firefox??

Comment: @blasteralfred:  I don't know why it's broken in Firefox since I didn't know I should be troubleshooting exclusively in Firefox.  Is that the only browser with this issue?  Did you try any of the solutions posted below?  Perhaps you can respond to them so we know what won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle shows a hug gap between `logo` and the `menu` when the window is resized.  Is that what you want?

I think this is what you are after...

Change the `float`s to `display:inline-block;`s

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/wVBxy/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `float: right` from the `menu` element, or set it to `float: left`, depending on how you want logo2 to appear.